# WPF-mvvm. How can I achieve such view (design, gui)?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Please, look at picture - http://imgur.com/25DEe4h
My current design achieved by:

```
<GroupBox Header="Playlists" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,220,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="283" Width="497">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PlayLists}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPL}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="487" Margin="0,0,-2,0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <StackPanel>
                      <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding plName}" />
                 </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: You're not saying what is your problem, and the link to the image doesn't work (error 502 every time). It's going to be difficult to answer your question... Please post your image to a site that actually works (e.g. imgur.com), and ask a real question!

Comment: edited http://imgur.com/25DEe4h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

> Music.cs

```
public class Music
{
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> PlayList { get; set; }
}
```

> ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Music> Musics { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        FillMusic();
    }

    void FillMusic()
    {
        Musics = new ObservableCollection<Music> 
        { new Music { Genre = "POP Music", PlayList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "sample1", "sample2", } },
        new Music { Genre = "Club Music", PlayList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "sample1", "sample2", "sample3"} },
        new Music { Genre = "Retro", PlayList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "sample1" } }};
    }
}
```

> xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
 }
```

> xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Stackoverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stackoverflow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="InnerListBoxItemstyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,2,0,2">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="10,1,1,1"/>
                    </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="OuterListBoxItemstyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue" Margin="0,2,0,2">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Genre}" Margin="20,1,0,10" Foreground="LimeGreen" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
                    </Border>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PlayList}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource InnerListBoxItemstyle}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid >
    <GroupBox>
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="PlayList" Foreground="LimeGreen" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
        </GroupBox.Header>
        <GroupBox.Content>
            <Grid>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Musics}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource OuterListBoxItemstyle}"  BorderThickness="0">
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox.Content>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

> Outupt

[image: Output]

There can be lot more improvement in style i keep that for you :). I gotta go